# Regex to match only letters

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex that matches only letters?

Comment: What's your definition of `characters`? ASCII? Kanji? Iso-XXXX-X? UTF8?

Comment: What's your definition of `regex`? Perl? Emacs? Grep?

Comment: I have noticed that **\p{L}** for a letter and **/u** flag for the Unicode matches any letter in my regex i.e. `/\p{L}+/u`

Answer (score 604):

Use a character set: `[a-zA-Z]` matches one letter from A–Z in lowercase and uppercase. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches one or more letters and `^[a-zA-Z]+$` matches only strings that consist of one or more letters only (`^` and `$` mark the begin and end of a string respectively).

If you want to match other letters than A–Z, you can either add them to the character set: `[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]`. Or you use predefined character classes like the [Unicode character property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) class `\p{L}` that describes the Unicode characters that are letters.

Comment: That's a very ASCII-centric solution. This will break on pretty much any non-english text.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: It will rather break on languages using non-latin characters.

Comment: Already breaks on 90% of German text, don't even mention French or Spanish. Italian might still do pretty well though.

Comment: that depends on what definition of "latin character" you choose. J, U, Ö, Ä can all be argued to be latin characters or not, based on your definition. But they are all used in languages that use the "latin alphabet" for writing.

Comment: \p{L} matches all the umlauts sedilla accents etc, so you should go with that.

Comment: Works well in a selector engine for determining if the selector is just a tag name.

Comment: What do you do if you can't use `[]` because Python is too thick to understand nestings?

Comment: Instead of keep adding characters like adding äöüßÄÖÜ, you can go: ^[a-zA-Z]\p{L}+$ to include most of the western alphabets.

Comment: This is not even a good solutions for English ASCII text. Try "naïve" or "café" (both English words compatible with extended ASCII)

Comment: @Pablo, your suggestion would restrict the match to words beginning with an unaccecented character from a western-European alphabet, missing many Scandinavian words.  You could just use `^\p{L}+$` as already suggested in the answer.

There is are uses for `[A-Z]` though - e.g. validating a map grid reference.  You can also use the `i` (case insensitive) modifier.

Comment: @IvoWetzel this [regex demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/cad5601c9336) works for German, French, Spanish, Italian & more.

Answer (score 270):

`\p{L}` matches anything that is a Unicode letter if you're interested in alphabets beyond the Latin one

Comment: not in all regex flavours. For example, vim regexes treat `\p` as "Printable character".

Comment: [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) suggests only java, .net, perl, jgsoft, XML and XPath regexes support \p{L}. But major omissions: python and ruby (though python has the regex module).

Comment: @Philip Potter: Ruby supports Unicode character properties using that exact same syntax.

Comment: I think this should be `\p{L}\p{M}*+` to cover letters made up of multiple codepoints, e.g. a letter followed by accent marks. As per http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: with python 3 this yields an error `bad escape \p at position 0`

Comment: Doesn't work in firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1361876

Comment: **JavaScript** needs `u` after regex to detect the unicode group: `/\p{Letter}/gu`

Comment: PHP supports this too, and doesn't seem to need the `u` modifier.  Note you can also use `\p{Lu}` and `\p{Ll}` for uppercase and lowercase respectively.  If you are trying to match prose (as opposed to code), this is the correct answer, but note @ZoFreX's comment.

Answer (score 72):

Depending on your meaning of "character":

> `[A-Za-z]` - all letters *(uppercase and lowercase)*

> `[^0-9]` - all non-digit characters

Comment: I meant lettters. It doesn't appear to be working though. preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+/', $name);

Comment: [A-Za-z] is just the declaration of characters you can use. You still need to declare howmany times this declaration has to be used: [A-Za-z]{1,2} (to match 1 or 2 letters) or [A-Za-z]{1,*} (to match 1 or more letters)

Comment: well à, á, ã, Ö, Ä... are letters too, so are অ, আ, ই, ঈ, Є, Ж, З, ﺡ, ﺥ, ﺩא, ב, ג, ש, ת, ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_%28alphabet%29

Comment: @phuclv: Indeed, but that depends on the encoding, and the encoding is part of the settings of the program (either the default config or the one declared in a config file of the program). When I worked on different languages, I used to store that in a constant, in a config file.

Comment: @CatalinaChircu encoding is absolutely irrelevant here. Encoding is a way to encode a code point in a character set in binary, for example UTF-8 is an encoding for Unicode. Letters OTOH depends on the language, and if one says `[A-Za-z]` are letters then the language that's being used must be specified

Comment: @phuclv: Indeed, I should have mentioned the language, not the encoding. The language is important and finding the letters in English is not the same as finding the letters in Spanish or French. If you do not take into account the diacritics in these languages you can cut words in two.

Answer (score 37):

The closest option available is

```
[\u\l]+
```

which matches a sequence of uppercase and lowercase letters. However, it is not supported by all editors/languages, so it is probably safer to use

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

as other users suggest

Comment: Won't match any special characters though.

Comment: For a long time I had been using [A-z]+ but just noticed this allows a few special characters like ` and [ to slip in. [a-zA-Z]+ is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 28):

You would use

```
/[a-z]/gi
```

- `[]` checks for any characters between given inputs
- `a-z` covers the entire alphabet
- `g` globally throughout the whole string
- `i` getting upper and lowercase

Comment: For non Latin letter. Here is the [regex](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/cad5601c9336) that worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

In python, I have found the following to work:

```
[^\W\d_]
```

This works because we are creating a new character class (the `[]`) which excludes (`^`) any character from the class `\W` (everything NOT in `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), also excludes any digit (`\d`) and also excludes the underscore (`_`).

That is, we have taken the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and removed the `0-9` and `_` bits. You might ask, wouldn't it just be easier to write `[a-zA-Z]` then, instead of `[^\W\d_]`? You would be correct if dealing only with ASCII text, but when dealing with unicode text:

> \W
>
> Matches any character which is not a word character. This is the opposite of \w. > If the ASCII flag is used this becomes the equivalent of [^a-zA-Z0-9_].

^ from [the python re module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

That is, we are taking everything considered to be a word character in unicode, removing everything considered to be a digit character in unicode, and also removing the underscore.

For example, the following code snippet

```
import re
regex = "[^\W\d_]"
test_string = "A;,./>>?()*)&^*&^%&^#Bsfa1 203974"
re.findall(regex, test_string)
```

Returns

```
['A', 'B', 's', 'f', 'a']
```

Comment: What about non Latin letter? For example `çéàñ`. Your regex is less readable than `\p{L}`

Comment: Clever answer. Works perfectly for accented letters as well.

Comment: @Toto Python's `re` module doesn't support Unicode properties. You have to use the re.UNICODE flag for Unicode support. Hence the `[^\W\d_]` pattern, which is the closest thing for "any letter" in Python's regex engine.

Comment: @Toto Here is the [regex](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/a2e3996e8be8) that works for non Latin letter in Python.

Answer (score 18):

Java:

```
String s= "abcdef";

if(s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
     System.out.println("string only contains letters");
}
```

Comment: it doesn't include diacritic signs such as `ŹŻŚĄ`

Comment: ^ or any Cyrillic letters

Answer (score 16):

Regular expression which few people has written as "/^[a-zA-Z]$/i" is not correct because at the last they have mentioned **/i** which is for case insensitive and after matching for first time it will return back. Instead of **/i** just use **/g** which is for global and you also do not have any need to put **^ $** for starting and ending.

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/g
```

1. **[a-z_]+** match a single character present in the list below
2. Quantifier: **+** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
3. **a-z** a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
4. **A-Z** a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
5. **g** modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

Answer (score 14):

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/
```

Super simple example. Regular expressions are extremely easy to find online.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 13):

For PHP, following will work fine

```
'/^[a-zA-Z]+$/'
```

Comment: But, this will not work for Latin character. Check it [here](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/1cd85790fcb9).

Answer (score 10):

Just use `\w` or `[:alpha:]`. It is an escape sequences which matches only symbols which might appear in words.

Comment: `\w` may not be a good solution in all cases. At least in PCRE, `\w` can match other characters as well. Quoting the [PHP manual](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php): "*A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.*".

Comment: words include other characters from letters

Comment: `\w` means match letters and numbers

Comment: how to match words with only alphabet characters?

Answer (score 10):

Use character groups

```
\D
```

Matches any character except digits 0-9

```
^\D+$
```

See example [here](https://regex101.com/r/owfkJP/1)

Comment: This will also match whitespace, symbols, etc. which does not seem to be what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 8):

So, I've been reading a lot of the answers, and most of them don't take exceptions into account, like letters with accents or diaeresis (á, à, ä, etc.).

I made a function in typescript that should be pretty much extrapolable to any language that can use RegExp. This is my personal implementation **for my use case** in TypeScript. What I basically did is add ranges of letters with each kind of symbol that I wanted to add. I also converted the char to upper case before applying the RegExp, which saves me some work.

```js
function isLetter(char: string): boolean {
  return char.toUpperCase().match('[A-ZÀ-ÚÄ-Ü]+') !== null;
}
```

If you want to add another range of letters with another kind of accent, just add it to the regex. Same goes for special symbols.

I implemented this function with TDD and I can confirm this works with, at least, the following cases:

```
    character | isLetter
    ${'A'}    | ${true}
    ${'e'}    | ${true}
    ${'Á'}    | ${true}
    ${'ü'}    | ${true}
    ${'ù'}    | ${true}
    ${'û'}    | ${true}
    ${'('}    | ${false}
    ${'^'}    | ${false}
    ${"'"}    | ${false}
    ${'`'}    | ${false}
    ${' '}    | ${false}
```

Comment: what about Arabic, Hebrew, Japanese etc.?

Comment: @VadimAidlin then you need to add it to the RegExp string like in the provided code.(`firstLetter-lastLetter`). To make sure that it works, you can implement a test that checks your use cases.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean any letters in any character encoding, then a good approach might be to delete non-letters like spaces `\s`, digits `\d`, and other special characters like:

```
[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\[\]:;'",\. ...more special chars... ]
```

Or use negation of above negation to directly describe any letters:

```
\S \D and [^  ..special chars..]
```

Pros:

- Works with all regex flavors.
- Easy to write, sometimes save lots of time.

Cons:

- Long, sometimes not perfect, but character encoding can be broken as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this regular expression : `[^\W\d_]` or `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: That is not what `[^\W|\d]` means

Comment: `[^\W|\d]` means not `\W` and not `|` and not `\d`. It has the same net effect since `|` is part of `\W` but the `|` does not work as you think it does. Even then that means it accepts the `_` character. You are probably looking for `[^\W\d_]`

Comment: I agree with you, it accepts the `_`. But "NOT" `|` is equal than "AND", so `[^\W|\d]` means : NOT `\W` **AND** NOT `\d`

Comment: `[^ab]` means not `a` and not `b`. `[^a|b]` means not `a` and not `|` and not `b`. To give a second example `[a|b|c|d]` is exactly the same as `[abcd|||]` which is exactly the same as `[abcd|]` - all of which equate to `([a]|[b]|[c]|[d]|[|])` the `|` is a literal character, not an OR operator. The OR operator is implied between each character in a character class, putting an actual `|` means you want the class to accept the `|` (pipe) character.

Answer (score 5):

Lately I have used this pattern in my forms to check names of people, containing letters, blanks and special characters like accent marks.

```
pattern="[A-zÀ-ú\s]+"
```

Comment: You should have look at an ASCII table. `A-z` matches more than just letters, as well as `À-ú`

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript**

If you want to return matched letters:

`('Example 123').match(/[A-Z]/gi)`   // *Result: ["E", "x", "a", "m", "p", "l", "e"]*

If you want to replace matched letters with stars ('*') for example:

`('Example 123').replace(/[A-Z]/gi, '*')` //Result: *"******* 123"*

Comment: For letters beyond english: `/\p{Letter}/gu` ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes#examples

Answer (score 2):

```js
/^[A-z]+$/.test('asd')
// true

/^[A-z]+$/.test('asd0')
// false

/^[A-z]+$/.test('0asd')
// false
```

Comment: Hello @jarraga. Welcome to SO, [did you read how to answer a question?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It should assist the clearance of your answer, and hence avoid down voting.

Answer (score 1):

pattern = /[a-zA-Z]/

puts "[a-zA-Z]: #{pattern.match("mine blossom")}"  OK

puts "[a-zA-Z]: #{pattern.match("456")}"

puts "[a-zA-Z]: #{pattern.match("")}"

puts "[a-zA-Z]: #{pattern.match("#$%^&*")}"

puts "[a-zA-Z]: #{pattern.match("#$%^&*A")}"       OK

Comment: And what about for instance, “Zażółć gęslą jaźń”?

Answer (score 1):

The answers here either do not cover all possible letters, or are incomplete.

**Complete regex to match ONLY unicode LETTERS, including those made up of multiple codepoints:**

```
^(\p{L}\p{M}*)+$
```

(based on [@ZoFreX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters/76790719#comment66380261_3617818) comment)

Test it here:
https://regex101.com/r/Mo5qdq/1

Answer (score 1):

```
[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]
```

Note: western bias.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me, ONLY unicode characters (not valid for numbers, special characters, emojis ...)

```
// notice: unicode: true
RegExp(r"^[\p{L}\p{M} ]*$", unicode: true)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$");

if (pattern.matcher("a").find()) {

   ...do something ......
}
```