# accepting only character input in text box

Tags: php, jquery

How to validate input box for only text input using jquery and php
e.g name **_** must accept only text input and no special character like "aaa@ or @@@ aaaa" and alpha numeric like "aaa123"

Comment: with javascript or with php ?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use regular expressions I think. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-only-letters) which is pretty much the same as yours (except that it isnt about jquery) with PHP and all..

**edit:**
Or as ComFreek points out, you can use the [ctype_alnum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) function!

**edit 2**
[ctype_alpha](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) is actually what you are looking for; all alphabetic characters.

> Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are alphabetic. In the standard C locale letters are just [A-Za-z] and ctype_alpha() is equivalent to (ctype_upper($text) || ctype_lower($text)) if $text is just a single character, but other languages have letters that are considered neither upper nor lower case.

Comment: I think regular expressions are a bit overkilled here, you could use [ctype_alnum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)

Comment: Cool-beans, didn't know about that function :) Thanks ComFreek

Comment: Actually, I think ctype_alpha might be better :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want both jquery and php validation, jquery for a better user experience and php for data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

regarding to this, you must look into the ascii table... A-Z is representing 65-90

you just need to detect the value that return when onkeyup in html...