# Issue with Jquery Validation for Name ( Characters only )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, validation

I'm having some trouble properly validating a name format with a predefined jquery validation tool ,

I want the name to accept characters only and i even used a correct regex but it is still accepting numbers .

I'm using this script : http://jqueryvalidation.org/

This is what i added basically :

```
names: function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/.test(value);
        },
```

FULL JQUERY FILE :

file 1 : http://jsfiddle.net/EjSbd/  (script.js)

file 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/qM4Uz/   (jquery.validate.js)

full : http://jsfiddle.net/EjSbd/  ( doesn't compile tho )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I far as I understand, you want letters only, so:

```
names: function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(value);

    },
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks . Need to learn regex again - i thought /w did not include numbers

Comment: @John_Nil: You're welcome. Here is an interesting site about regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

Agree with M42:

\w matches any alphanumerical character (word characters) including underscore (short for [a-zA-Z0-9_]).

[Regex to match only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-only-letters)