# Validate NIC field in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to validate NIC number text field in my vb form.  It should contain 9 numbers `[0-9]` and one letter (letter should be `"v"`) (first 9 characters are numbers,last one is a letter)
How do I validate such a thing using regular expression?
Can you help me with the code?
I'm new to this section.

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Comment: I didn't, I'm new to this area.

Answer (score 2):

The examples section in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) shows you.

To match a digit use `\d`

To match 9 numbers you state you want 9: `\d{9}`

To match a letter you want `[a-zA-Z]` (or something more complicated depending on what a [letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters) is). If you specifically want `v` then just allow `v` using `[v]`
i.e. `\d{9}[v]`

Test this with `Regex.IsMatch`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
If Not System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "[0-9]{9}v") Then
    MessageBox.Show("Not valid NIC")
End If
```