# Regular expression that accepts only characters, numbers and special characters not

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular expression that accepts as input characters (A..Z or a..z) and does not accept numbers and special characters.
I wrote this method and these patterns but it doesn't work:

```
 public static Pattern patternString = Pattern.compile("\\D*");
 public static Pattern special = Pattern.compile("[!@#$%&*,.()_+=|<>?{}\\[\\]~-]");

 public static boolean checkString(String input) {
    boolean bool_string = patternString.matcher(input).matches(); 
    boolean bool_special = !special.matcher(input).matches(); 
    return (bool_string && bool_special);
 }
```

`checkString` should return true if the input is: *hello*, *table*, *Fire*, *BlaKc*, etc.

`checkString` should return false if the input is: *10*, *tabl_e*, *+*, *hel/lo*, etc.

How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: this post i think is the answer for u  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
if (subjectString.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
    // It matched!
  } 
else {  // nah, it didn't match...  
     }
```

- no need to anchor the regex with `^` and `$` because the `matches` method only looks for full matches
- `[a-zA-Z]` is a character class that matches one character in the ranges `a-z` or `A-Z`
- the `+` quantifier makes the engine match that one or more times