# How to add validation in cake php to allow only characters?

Tags: validation, cakephp

I am new to cakephp. I have created a form to add users. I want to allow only characters for username. My code for validation is as follows:

```
public $validate = array(
       "username" => array(
           "required" => array(
                "rule" => array("notEmpty"),
                "message" => "Name is required"
            ) 
        ),
        "age" => array(
           "required" => array(
                "rule" => array("notEmpty"),
                "message" => "Age is required"
            )
        )
);
```

what should i add to allow only characters for username.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the "custom" rule](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::custom), which takes a regex:

```
"rule" => array('custom', '[a-zA-Z]'),
```

See [Regex to match only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters)

[CakePHP Validation manual page.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html)