# Regex to catch "-" character

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string :

```
Ümraniye Tapu Müdürlüğünde ve Ümraniye Belediyesi İmar Müdürlüğünde 20.08.2014 onay tarih ve 254 sayılı mimari projesi incelenmiştir.
```

I'm getting datetime : like this :

```
t = DateTime.Parse(Regex.Match(mimaristring, @"\d(\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)").Value);
```

I'm trying to get 254 like this :

```
num = Regex.Match(mimaristring,  @"(?<!\d\.)\b\d+(?:/\d+)?\b(?!\.\d)").Value;
```

I can catch **254** or **123/456** but now I also need to catch **123-456**. How can I catch that? Thanks.

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `-` and `/` to the character class `[-/]` that will match either a single `-` or a single `/`:

```
(?<!\d\.)\b\d+(?:[/-]\d+)?\b(?!\.\d)
                 ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5Cd%5C.)%5Cb%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5B%2F-%5D%5Cd%2B)%3F%5Cb(%3F!%5C.%5Cd)&i=%C3%9Cmraniye%20Tapu%20M%C3%BCd%C3%BCrl%C3%BC%C4%9F%C3%BCnde%20ve%20%C3%9Cmraniye%20Belediyesi%20%C4%B0mar%20M%C3%BCd%C3%BCrl%C3%BC%C4%9F%C3%BCnde%2020.08.2014%20onay%20tarih%20ve%20254-123%20say%C4%B1l%C4%B1%20mimari%20projesi%20incelenmi%C5%9Ftir.)

[image]