# using try and regex in python

Tags: python, regex, exception, try-catch

I'd like to use a try/except statement for checking that a string consists of letters only.
What is wrong with the following

```
class LetterError(Exception):
    pass

name = ""
while name=="":
    try:
        x = re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]',(input("Please enter a name: ")))
        raise LetterError
    except LetterError :
        print("Insert letters only")
```

Comment: Then you need to use at least `r'[a-zA-Z]+$'` with `re.match`. Then only raise the error `if not x`.

Comment: You are using only one letter out of `[A-Za-z]`. Add `+` like this `[A-Za-z]+`. It means many letters.

Comment: @monika I update regex. Have a look

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are raising error in all case. You need to add a condition and also, you don't need your custom error. Regex from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617808/5567387

```
name = ""
while name == "":
    name = raw_input("Please enter a name: ")
    is_valid = re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$', name)
    if not is_valid:
        name = ""
```

Comment: Have you tested it? There are multiple issues.

Comment: The OP wanted to check if a string consists of letters only. The current solution would accept if the string has numbers in it e.g. if it is `abcd345` or `abcd5efgh`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `[a-zA-Z]` will match only one character out of given range `[a-zA-Z]`.

I suppose by name you mean multiple characters. Thus use `[a-zA-Z]+` for matching multiple characters.