# regex - Why doesn't this work to make sure a variable has some text?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have been looking around and googling about regex and I came up with this to make sure some variable has letters in it (and nothing else).

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*$/
```

In my mind `^` denotes the start of the string, the token `[a-zA-Z]` should in my mind make sure only letters are allowed. The star should match everything in the token, and the $-sign denotes the end of the string I'm trying to match.

But it doesn't work, when I try it on [regexr](https://regexr.com/) it doesn't work sadly. What's the correct way to do it then? I would also like to allow hyphen and spaces, but figured just starting with letters are good enough to start with and expand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : this is what you are looking for.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

The star `*` quantifier means "zero or more", meaning your regexp will match everytime even with an empty string as subject. You need the `+` quantifier instead (meaning "one or more") to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to match at least one character which could also be a whitespace or a hyphen you could add those to your character class [`^[A-Za-z -]+$`](https://regexr.com/3jh8a) using the plus `+` sign for the [repetition](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

If you want to use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match at least one character which can contain an upper or lowercase character, you could shorten your pattern to [`^[a-z]+$`](https://regexr.com/3jh8j) and use the `i` [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to make the regex case insensitive. To also match a hyphen and a whitespace, this could look like [`^[a-z -]+$`](https://regexr.com/3jh8d)

For example:

```
$strings = [
    "TeSt",
    "Te s-t",
    "",
    "Te4St"
];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if(preg_match('#^[a-z -]+$#i', $string, $matches)){
        echo $matches[0] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

That would result in:

> TeSt
>
> Te s-t

[Output php](https://3v4l.org/vOTSm)