# How to write a regex that matches a string containing at least 4 letters?

Tags: regex

Ex:  I want to ensure that a string must contain A, B, C, D

```
  test strings:
  "ABCDF" will be true 
  "AACDF" will be false (it not contains 'B') 
  "AABCDFG" will be true (it allows duplicated words)
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Do some research, try it out, we will help if you demonstrate some effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters)

Comment: yes, Nic3500, I read and try some such as (*.[abcd]{1,}.*){4,} , it can not exclude the string like 'aabbff'

Comment: @antonio-steve to combat that look into how anchoring works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a regex matching **a single word** containing 4 particular
letters (in some bigger text), you can use:

```
(?=\w*A)(?=\w*B)(?=\w*C)(?=\w*D)\w+
```

It contains 4 positive lookups.
Each of them looks for `A`, `B`, `C`  and `D`, respectively,
after a number of word chars (possibly 0).
Then there is the actual matching part - a sequence of word chars.

You should use also `g` (global) option, to match **all** such words.

Another possibility is that you want to verify **the whole string** (something
like password criteria verification).
Then the regex can be:

```
(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C)(?=.*D).+
```

The differences are that:

- Each lookahead looks for the particular char after any number
  of **any** chars (instead of word chars).
- The matching part contains also any chars (matches the whole string).
- `g` option is not needed.