# Check a string for letters or whitespaces C#

Tags: c#

I have already checked the similar past questions but did not find the exact piece of code. I found only regex solution.

I am looking for a way to use Boolean to check whether my string is build only from letters and whitespaces or it includes other characters. 
I want to use char.isletter and char.whitespace.

Comment: Can you share some sample input strings and the expected output for each of them? Can you also share whatever code you have written for this and explain what exact issue you are facing in that?

Comment: what's wrong with RegEx BTW?

Comment: Like `"ABC DEF".All(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsWhiteSpace(c))`?

Comment: If you want boolean then `Regex.IsMatch()` is also suitable for you.

Comment: Please provide more information about what type of comparison you're trying to do. `bool` is a value type in C#. Saying you want to use boolean to check if your string contains spaces is like saying you want to use integers to check if a number is a certain value: it tells us nothing about how you want to do the comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use Linq `All`:

```
bool onlyLettersOrWhiteSpace = str.All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsLetter(c));
```

`using System.Linq` required.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `System.Linq`'s `All()`:

```
bool onlyLettersAndWhitespace = input.All(i => char.IsLetter(i) || char.IsWhiteSpace(i));
```

Just for completeness here's the RegEx version:

```
bool onlyLettersAndWhitespace = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\A[\p{L}\s]+\Z");
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/1yhFEm/3)

Comment: FYI - the solutions don't produce the same result with different languages - none latin characters - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ntguvm

Comment: @RandRandom yep, that's true. Didn't thought of that. But honestly I'm not sure if there is a way to check for 'all' letters with Regex (w/o making it horribly long). I'm going to make it so that both produce the same result and only accept latin characters.

Comment: FYI - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters - so you could have changed the regex to `\p{L}` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/869O2I