# Filter only alphabetic values in tableau

Tags: mysql, tableau-api, visualization, dashboard

I have column in tableau with following values:
1234
3456
6789
camp-1
camp-2
camp-3

I only want to show filter with values
camp-1
camp-2
camp-3

How can I only select the alphabetic values in filter in tableau?

Comment: Do you mean that other values are hidden from that filter except these three?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not clear about what you want to include and what you want to exclude.  To explain better, I took an elaborated example

[image]

**Case-1** If you want to search/filter for `digits at start`, use this calculated field

```
REGEXP_MATCH([Field1], '^[0-9]')
```

**Case-2** If you want to search for `numbers anywhere`, use this

```
REGEXP_MATCH([Field1], '(.*)[0-9]')
```

**Case-3** If `digits only` are required

```
REGEXP_MATCH([Field1], '^[0-9]+$')
```

**case-4** for `alphabet at start` use this

```
REGEXP_MATCH([Field1], '^[:alpha:]')
```

Results of all matches are shown below

[image]

**Note** Combining `numbers anywhere` **AND** `alphabet at start` you can filter out case1, case2 and case3 only.

Good Luck

Comment: Hi, Thanks . It helped me to find my desired output

Comment: Glad to have been help.  Please feel free to accept and upvote, as usually desired on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If the Tableau column contains a mixture of numbers and text, the column will be a text column and all content will be considered as text. This reduces the problem to that of identifying specific rows that contain non-numeric values.

This requires some string manipulation and comparison. If you know that the structure of the content in those rows is predictable (eg the first character is always a letter when there are non numeric characters in the row) then a simple equation will filter on those rows:

```
if ascii(left([Text And Numbers],1) )>57 then 'text' else 'number' END
```

This exploits the observation that the ASCII decimal code for the digit 9 is 57 and most of the ASCII characters with higher codes are letters or punctuation (which is a fair assumption if nothing other than numbers, letters or punctuation are present in your data).

Obviously, if letters and numbers could appear anywhere in the string you need a more complex function but Tableau provides the option to use *regular expressions* which can code  much more complex text analysis like is any alphabetic character present in a string (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters) for some ideas of the appropriate regex expressions).