# How to make edit text accept only letters in android

Tags: java, android, string, validation, android-edittext

I am validating an `EditText` and want to restrict input to [a-z][A-z] and a space.

For instance

```
Aftab Abbs
```

Not sure how to proceed, is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: [Regex to match only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3617797/3290339)

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText state = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtState);

            Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
            Matcher ms = ps.matcher(state.getText().toString());
            boolean bs = ms.matches();
            if (bs == false) {
                if (ErrorMessage.contains("invalid"))
                    ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "state,";
                else
                    ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "invalid state,";

            }
```