# Replace words in a a string randomly

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a script that will take a text string and will allow me replace random words. For example:

```
$str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
```

I will out put as and replace couple words like this:

> The quick ______ fox jumps over the ____ dog

I can probably do this by first splitting the string into array

```
$arr = str_word_count($str, 1);
```

And then replace `$arr[2]` and `$arr[7]`.

The issue that I think I'll have if there are non-words in the string, like punctuation:

```
$str = "The quick brown fox, named Jack, jumps over the lazy dog; and Bingo was his...";
```

How do I go about resolving this? Ideas?

Comment: You mean, for example, "fox," will be replaced instead of "fox"? (you mean this is the problem?)

Comment: It appears you could use `preg_replace` on each substring. As `preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/',...` etc. Words that are contractions could still be a problem though if single quotes are also possible as punctuation.

Comment: @jpf Selecting words without the punctuation is not the issue, `str_word_count` already does that. I believe the issue is the reconstruction of the sentence from the resulting array - it would lose all its original punctuation in the word replacement process. Though, `preg_replace` on randomly selected words is a good idea.

Comment: @santa Is the number of replacements also random? Can the string be made of multiple sentences or will it always be a single one?

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I actually did mean to replace with an underline, instead of other words. Yes the words will be replaced randomly. I'll probably add a count() to check how many letters in a  word to replace with the same number of _ (underscore). And yes, the main challenge was to reconstruct the sentence with the original punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
   $test1 = "test1";
    $test2 = "test2";
    $test3 = "Bingo2";
    // set new words


    $str = "The quick brown fox, named Jack, jumps over the lazy dog; and Bingo was his...";
    $re = explode(" ", $str);
    // split them on space in array $re
    echo $str  . "<br>";
    $num = 0;

    foreach ($re as $key => $value) {
        echo $value . "<br>";
        $word = "";

        switch (true) {
            case (strpos($value, 'Jack') !== false):
                // cheak if each value in array has in it wanted word to replace 
                // and if it does
                $new = explode("Jack", $value);
                // split at that word just to save punctuation
                $word = $test1 . $new[1];
                //replace the word and add back punctuation
                break;
            case (strpos($value, 'dog') !== false):
                $new1 = explode("dog", $value);
                $word = $test2 . $new1[1];
                break;
            case (strpos($value, 'Bingo') !== false):
                $new2 = explode("Bingo", $value);
                $word = $test3 . $new2[1];
                break;
            default:
                $word = $value;
                // if no word are found to replace just leave it
        }

        $re[$num++] = $word;
        //push new words in order back into array
    };


    echo  implode(" ", $re);
        // join back with space
```

Result:

```
The quick brown fox, named test1, jumps over the lazy test2; and Bingo2 was his...
```

It works with or without punctuation.

But keep in mind if you have `Jack` and `Jacky` for example you will need to add additional logic such as checking if punctuation part does not have any letters in it with [Regex to match only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters), if it does skip it, it means it was not full match. Or soothing similar.

**EDIT (based on comments):**

```
$wordstoraplce = ["Jacky","Jack", "dog", "Bingo","dontreplace"];
$replacewith = "_";
$word = "";
$str = "The quick brown fox, named Jack, jumps over the lazy dog; and Bingo was his...";
echo $str . "<br>";
foreach ($wordstoraplce as $key1 => $value1) {
    $re = explode(" ", $str);
    foreach ($re as $key => $value) {
        if((strpos($value, $value1) !== false)){
            $countn=strlen($value1);
            $new = explode($value1, $value);
            if (!ctype_alpha ($new[1])){
                $word = " " . str_repeat($replacewith,$countn) . $new[1]. " ";
            }else{
                $word = $value;
            }
        }else{
            $word = $value;
        };
        //echo  $word;  
        $re[$key] = $word;      
    };
    $str =  implode(" ", $re);
};
echo $str;
```

RESULT:

```
The quick brown fox, named Jack, jumps over the lazy dog; and Bingo was his...
The quick brown fox, named ____, jumps over the lazy ___; and _____ was his...
```

Comment: Sorry, I clarified a bit more in my comment above, but this is a great help and will let me push further. Instead of exact words it'll probably be a string on random keys that will be replaced.

Comment: @santa Yeah i read it now, this can easily be converted to that usage case i believe. If the number of words to replace is (n), just create a loop for that number of words and use just one `if` or `case` as shown from above and go word by word.

Comment: @santa Not sure what you meant by  "random keys that will be replaced" But my last edit  can surly be adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

I think a much better apporach would be to use a regex, because you don't just allow commas, but everything which is not a word character. Also regexes are much faster than normal splittings or substrings in loops.
My Solution would be:

```
<?php
function randomlyRemovedWords($str)
{
    $sentenceParts = [];

    $wordCount = preg_match_all("/([\w']+)([^\w']*)/", $str, $sentenceParts, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    for ($i = 0;$i < $wordCount / 4;$i++)
    { //nearly every fourth word will be changed
        $index = rand(0, $wordCount - 1);

        $sentenceParts[$index][1] = preg_replace("/./", "_", $sentenceParts[$index][1]);
    }

    $str = "";
    foreach ($sentenceParts as $part)
    {
        $str .= $part[1] . $part[2];
    }

    return $str;
}

echo randomlyRemovedWords("The quick brown fox, doesn't jumps over, the lazy dog.");
echo "\n<br>\n";
echo randomlyRemovedWords("The quick brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog.");
```

which results in

```
The quick brown ___, _______ jumps over, the ____ dog.
<br>
The quick brown fox, jumps ____, ___ ____ dog.
```

This way you can be sure to ignore all nonword characters and remove words randomly.

Comment: I like this! I wish I could accept more than one answer. This one is definitely a different approach and I like the brevity. Definitely +1