# Get Words before/between/after special characters

Tags: r, string, text

I have strings like this one `x <- "123/456/789"`. I want to do three different things

1. Get the first word before `/`, that is, `123`
2. Get the word between two `/`: `456`
3. Get the last word, the one afte the last `/`

I know there are some functions like `gsub` and packages like `stingr` but I did not find something useful

Comment: Maybe try `strsplit(x, "/")` ?

Comment: or `read.table(text=x, sep="/")` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get it to work using `gsub` and `str_extract` from `{stringr}`:

```
# Get 123
gsub("/\\d*", "", x)

# Get 456
gsub("/", "", stringr::str_extract(x, "/\\d*/"))

# Get 789
gsub("\\d*/", "", x)
```

This results in:

```
[1] "123"

[1] "456"

[1] "789"
```

In the RegEx, `\\d*` indicates one or more digits, but if your word consists of other characters you could also use a [different indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the digits and parse as numbers, you can try

```
> scan(text = x, sep = "/", quiet = TRUE)
[1] 123 456 789
```